# How to select a latest value row in mysql table for 2 days

Tags: mysql

i am finding it difficult to wrap my head around this. for example if i have a table like so :

```
table: cat
  -------------------------------------------------------------
  | id       | currency   |bank         |created_at           |
  -------------------------------------------------------------
  | 1        | a          |1            |2015-05-12 19:30:55  |
  | 2        | a          |1            |2015-05-12  20:30:55 |
  | 3        | b          |2            |2015-05-12  19:30:55 |
  | 4        | s          |1            |2015-05-13 19:30:55  |
  | 5        | b          |2            |2015-05-13  23:30:55 |
  | 6        | b          |2            |2015-05-13  19:30:55 |
  ----------------------------------------------------
```

my expected result :

```
 -------------------------------------------------------------
  | id       | currency   |bank         |created_at           |
  -------------------------------------------------------------
  | 2        | a          |1            |2015-05-12  20:30:55 |
  | 3        | b          |2            |2015-05-12  19:30:55 |
  | 4        | s          |1            |2015-05-13 19:30:55  |
  | 5        | b          |2            |2015-05-13  23:30:55 |
  ----------------------------------------------------
```

what i have tried :

```
SELECT p.id,p.currencyname, p.bank, date(p.created_at) as d, max(time(created_at)) as t, p.currencyname from cat as p  GROUP by p.currencyname, d
```

Comment: Please can you explain why the expected result should look like that?

Comment: @DhruvSaxena i just want the latest entry of a bank for a particular currency for the particular date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want the latest (largest time value) row for each currency for each calendar day.  As you use SQL professionally, with respect, it's critically important for you to take time to think through your requirements and describe them precisely.

Here's how you get the result you want.

First, you want to find the `created_at` value of the latest (`MAX()`) row for each currency in each calendar day (`DATE()`).  The query to do that looks like this (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0e097/1/0):

```
            SELECT DATE(created_at) day, currency, MAX(created_at) created_at
              FROM cat
             GROUP BY DATE(created_at), currency
```

You then use that as a subquery, and join it to your table. The join will extract the detail records from your table. You order it so it makes sense (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0e097/2/0).

```
 SELECT cat.id, cat.currency, cat.bank, cat.created_at
   FROM cat
   JOIN (
                 SELECT DATE(created_at) day, currency, MAX(created_at) created_at
                  FROM cat
                 GROUP BY DATE(created_at), currency
        ) a ON cat.currency = a.currency AND cat.created_at = a.created_at
  ORDER BY cat.id
```